# Extracting exactly K elements with maximum sum from a 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

**Problem statement**:

> Given a `N*M` matrix, and an integer `K`, you need to choose exactly K integers from the matrix, such that the sum of the selected K numbers is maximum.
> But here lies the catch, while selecting numbers from a particular row, say the `i-th` row, we can only select the `j-th` element of that row only if we have selected the first (j-1) elements from that row as well.

**Constraints**: `1 <= N <= 50`; `1 <= M <= 100`; `1 <= K <= N*M`; `|matrix[i][j]| <= 100`
**Example**: N = 4, M = 4, K = 5

```
matrix = {  
{1, 2,  3, 4},  
{3, 4,  1, 1},  
{4, 5, 20, 1},  
{1, 2,  3, 4}};
```

**Expected Output**: 36 (By selecting 3 and 4 from *Row 2* & 4, 5 and 20 from *Row 3*).
My approach: For each row, I've calculated the prefix sum up to each column along with averages (as `preSum[j] / (j+1)`) and stored it in the `maxSum` array. Then sorted the array in reverse order and greedily summed the elements with higher average values till K elements are found.

```java
import java.util.*;
class Solution
{
    public static int getMaximumKSum(int[][] matrix, int N, int M, int K)
    {
        int preSum = 0, MAX = 0;
        RowSum average [] = new RowSum [N*M];
        for (int i=0, z=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            preSum = 0;
            for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
            {
                preSum += matrix[i][j];
                average[z++] = new RowSum(i, j+1, preSum, ((double)preSum/(j+1)));
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(average, (x, y) -> Double.compare(y.average, x.average));
        //System.out.println( Arrays.toString(average) );

        Set<Integer> row = new HashSet<>();
        for (RowSum S : average)
        {
            if (K <= 0) break; // All `K` elements found!
            if (!row.contains(S.row) && S.n<=K)
            {
                MAX += S.sum;
                row.add(S.row);
                K -= S.n;
            }
        }
        return MAX;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N = 4, M = 4, K = 5;
        int [][] matrix = {{1, 2,  3, 4},
                           {3, 4,  1, 1},
                           {4, 5, 20, 1},
                           {1, 2,  3, 4}};
        System.out.println(getMaximumKSum(matrix, N, M, K));
    }
}
class RowSum
{
    int row,n,sum; // rowNo | number of elements | total sum of 'n' elements
    double average; // = sum / n
    RowSum(int a, int b, int c, double d)
    {
        row = a; n = b; sum = c; average = d;
    }
    public String toString()
    { return String.format("(%d*%.2f)", n, average); }
}
```

My code is giving the desired result for the custom inputs but on submission, it's giving a *wrong* verdict.
So, either my approach is completely wrong (then please suggest a correct way to solve this) or
it's failing on some edge cases (then please suggest appropriate modifications). Thanks.

Comment: Does the matrix {{0,99},{50,0},{1,0}} break your greedily approach? It will take 50 (cause (0+99)/2 < 50) and 1, but the correct answer is 0 + 99.

Comment: @Nikxp I think so, maybe I'm selecting the elements incorrectly.

Comment: Can you prove the correctness of using prefix average sums?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the i-th and j-th in the task description?

Comment: @Surt Ok, let's say we want to select 5 from the `i=3`rd row. So, as 5 is in the `j=2`th column, we can't select it alone as there are other elements appearing before 5. Hence, both 4 & 5 must be selected. Similarly, if we want to select 20 (`a[2][2]`), then we must select 4 (`a[2][0]`) & 5 (`a[2][1]`) as well. Hence, selected elements would be 4, 5 and 20. The same applies to the other rows.

Comment: I guess that the average can only be used in heuristics, where it might tell the most likely row to add from.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Your task is looks similary to Knapsack problem - well known and complicated problem. There is no known polynomial algorithm (polinomial from  matrix length) for solving Knapsack. But because value in matrix are limited you can try to adapt [Dynamic programming in-advance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Moreover it seems like "Multiple-choice Knapsack Problem" you can try to find it's [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832674/solve-multiple-choice-knapsack-mckp-with-dynamic-programming).

---

### How to reduce this task to Knapsack problem.

We will use only special matrix. Matrix with one nonzero value in each row. for example:

```
matrix = {  
{0, 0, 3, 0},  
{3, 0, 0, 0},  
{0, 0, 20, 0},  
{0, 0, 0, 2}};
```

For this type of matrix your task is Knapsack problem, where value in row is value(price) of item. And position of non zero element in the row is it's weight. For 3-rd row we have item with value(price) 20 and weight 3.

So if we want to solve Knapsack problem we can create special matrix for it and solve topic's task. Knapsack is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness), but it's not enought to be NP-Hard, because this reduction time depends on weight of items (Thanks @kaya3 for report)

Comment: This isn't a polynomial-time reduction because the size of the resulting matrix depends on the *values* in the knapsack problem instance.

Comment: @kaya3 Right! My mistake. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

Using

- knapsack - dynamic programming
- the row position +1 is the weight
- the value is the prefix sum.
- so we have N*M items & weights though only one from each row can be chosen
- CR is a helper that walks through the matrix

Pseudo code (untested...)

```
int [][] matrix = {{1, 2,  3, 4},
                   {3, 4,  1, 1},
                   {4, 5, 20, 1},
                   {1, 2,  3, 4}};
int [N][M] presum;
dict mem = {};

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  sum = 0
  for (j= 0; j < N; j++)
    presum[i][j] = sum+matrix[i][j]


CR(col, row, C)
  if (row > 0)
    res = KS(col, row-1, C)
  else if (col > 0)
    res = KS(col-1, M-1, C)
  else 
    res = 0
  return res

KS(col, row, C)
  if (col < 0 || row < 0) || C ==  0) 
    return 0
  if (!mem.find({col,row,C})
    return mem[{col,row,C}]

  if (row+1 > C) # weight is row+1
    row = C # no need to check anything greater than C
    res = CR(col, row, C)
  else
    unused = CR(col, row, C)

    # if used we can't use any more from this row, hence row = 0 in call to CR
    used =   presum[col][row] + CR(col, 0, C - (row + 1))  

    result = max(used, unused)
  
  mem[{col,row,C}] = result

  return result

KS(N-1, M-1, K)
```

Should be O(N*M*K)